# PHP CURL Passing Concatenation Variable in HTTPHeader

Tags: php, curl

I am new to php and couldn't find much on passing variable in HTTPHeader within curl. Below is the code I have in my curl header and not sure if the variable concatenation is correct in the Cookie line. Thanks in advance.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Cookie: ID=" . $ID . "; ID2=" . $ID2 . "; ID3=" . $ID3 . "", //proper format "Cookie: ID=xxxx; ID2= yyyy; ID3= zzzz"
```

Comment: You should send cookies using `CURLOPT_COOKIE` rather than `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. But either way, your format is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your format is correct. You can see documenation in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) and the official specification in [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4).

However, `curl` has a distinct option for cookies, so you should use

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ID=" . $ID . "; ID2=" . $ID2 . "; ID3=" . $ID3");
```

There's no need for `. ""` at the end, I never understand why people feel the need to add this when concatenating strings.

Comment: you miss closing brace. Also please avoid concatenation madness as this is error prone which is seen in your answer as you have invalid syntax there. Use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ID={$ID}; ID2={$ID2}; ID3={$ID3}");` which is far clearer.

Comment: I normally use that style, but when I'm answering questions I usually just copy the OP's style. The choice between concatenation and substitution is very personal.

Comment: Marcin, that's helpful as I didn't realize {} is equivalent of concatenation. Thanks,

Comment: It's not really an equivalent. Please see [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) as there are some important details, namely single quoted vs double quoted strings.